# Difference between long.Class and Long.TYPE

Tags: java, junit, autoboxing

Do they both return the same thing i.e Long Class. Actually i was using this within PrivilegedAccessor to pass as following

```
PrivilegedAccessor.invokeMethod(MyClass,
                "MyMethod", new Object[] { arg1, arg2 },
                new Class[] { long.class, Date.class });
```

Alternatively I can use

```
PrivilegedAccessor.invokeMethod(MyClass,
                    "MyMethod", new Object[] { arg1, arg2 },
                    new Class[] { Long.TYPE, Date.class });
```

Which is better to be used keeping in mind autoboxing / unboxing overheads.

** I am passing primitive long from the Test and even the tested method expects primitive long only.

Comment: `System.out.println(Long.TYPE == long.class);` Produces `true`. S the two are identical. I doubt there would be any autoboxing.

Comment: I have tried to look this up in the JLS, but must be looking in the wrong place. Interesting question though. 1+

Comment: AFAIK `Long.TYPE` pre-dates `long.class`  I prefer the later.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They both represent the `long` primitive type.  They are exactly the same, even in the compiled bytecode.  Sample program:

```
public class Main
{
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Class<Long> c = Long.TYPE;
      Class<Long> c1 = long.class;
   }
}
```

Then, using `javap -c Main`:

```
c:\dev\src\misc>javap -c Main
Compiled from "Main.java"
public class Main {
  public Main();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":
()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/Long.TYPE:Ljava/lang/Class;
       3: astore_1
       4: getstatic     #2                  // Field java/lang/Long.TYPE:Ljava/lang/Class;
       7: astore_2
       8: return
}
```

Answer (score 2):

These are exactly the same.

```
long.class == Long.TYPE; //always true
int.class == Integer.TYPE; //always true
float.class == Float.TYPE; // always true
```

The "TYPE" constants always have the value of the primitive class. I typically only use the TYPE thing, when I am not programming in Java, where the "int.class" syntax is not available.

**About the reflection and boxing thing:**

For reflection calls, primitive values are always boxed because Object arrays cannot contain primitive values. So it does not matter what you pass.

Also these two operations can return different methods:

```
Method fooInt = class.getMethod("foo", String.class, int.class);
Method fooInteger = class.getMethod("foo", String.class, Integer.class);

fooInt.equals(fooInteger); // false
```

Comment: There is no primitive class.
`public static final Class<Long>     TYPE = (Class<Long>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("long");`
This is a snippet from the JVM srouce code.
And the `getPrimitiveClass` method is described as:
`/*
     * Return the Virtual Machine's Class object for the named
     * primitive type.
     */
    static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);`

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to do such a thing is to pass `Long.class`. You will rarely see `long.class` in production code.

The memory footprint is NEGLIGIBLE. You could run benchmarks with both methods, calling them 1kkk times, and you wouldn't notice much of a difference.

Comment: Why would you pass a `Long.class` if you can pass a `long.class`?

Comment: Long is Object, so class, long is primitive. Even if the JVM makes the cast correctly "long.class" is not good idea.

Comment: There IS an important difference between `Long.class` and `long.class`: The first one is the class of the (reference) type `Long`, and the second is the class of the (primitive) type `long`. You have to be careful (and aware of) when to use the one or the other. The question was whether there is a difference between `long.class` and `Long.TYPE` - and the answer here is: No, there is no difference.

Comment: @Marco13 Can you provide different use cases?

Comment: Actually, AndiHofi already showed one in his answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/21464517/3182664) : Imagine you have a class with two methods: `void foo(Long x)` and `void foo(long x)`. In order to access either of them, you have to clearly say whether you want that with the `Long.class` argument type, or that with the `long.class` argument type.

Answer (score -2):

`long` is a primitive type and is not a Java Class. But `Long` is a type (extends `Object`) and thus is a Java Class. you can use either because Java has a Boxing and UnBoxing feature that converts one to another automatically for you.
But beware, primitive type tends to consume less memory, but the Class type has very useful methods in it. you decide what is better for you.

Edit:
Not sure why the down voting.
As the article below says: 
"The class literal of a primitive type or void is equivalent to a static variable reference to a pre-installed primitive type descriptor"
so `long.class` is not a Java class.

The Long.TYPE is assigned in the JVM source code as follows:
`public static final Class<Long> TYPE = (Class<Long>) Class.getPrimitiveClass("long");`

and the method used is as follows:

`static native Class getPrimitiveClass(String name);`

so `long.class`is a pointer to a primitive variable which is not a java class.

`long.class == Long.class` is evaluated as FALSE.

http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/courses/629/jdkdocs/guide/innerclasses/spec/innerclasses.doc9.html